# ¿Por qué MongoDB me da el error de conexión "No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión"?

Tags: mongodb

No me puedo conectar a **mongodb** me sale el siguiente error:

> Error with MongoDB connection: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.

Comment: Hola, no es un problema de MongoDB en sí sino de seguridad, deberías probar abrir los puertos, desactivar el firewall, y demás acciones relacionadas.

Comment: Ya intentaste desactivar el firewall y windows defender?

Comment: En mi caso fue resuelto cambiando "localhost" por "127.0.0.1".

Answer (score 1):

Dejo lo que yo hice y como lo pude resolver activando mongo DB desde servicios locales:

Windows+R -> services.msc

busque mongoDB server y click en iniciar..

probé todo lo demás desde el reparador del instalador de mongo DB hasta desactivar firewall y demás.. solo así lo pude resolver..

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente ya lo resolviste. Pero voy a dejar la solucion para futuros ingresantes a este thread. Basicamente se borro el path donde se ejecuta mongo lo que debemos hacer es agregar el path manualmente o instalar de nuevo mongo pero no entera sino que solamente le damos a la **opcion de reparar**. saludos

Comment: el error que menciona va mas bien sobre un firewall impidiendo la conexión de un recurso desconocido, dudo mucho que el path tenga algo que ver

Answer (score 0):

Verifiquen este archivo. En mi caso mi BD está en ubuntu,

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

Ahí agreguen su ip pública en la línea

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1,yourIp
```

Lo otro que pueden hacer es verificar que el firewal este correctamente configurado.

Comment: La respuesta, quizá no se adapte a lo que ha preguntado el OP. ya que a priori parece para un entorno Win. Puede serte de interés leer [answer]. También es válido y admisible, que realices otra pregunta poniendo esta en contexto, y que tú mismo, pongas la respuesta y la marques como aceptada, para ayudar a otros usuarios con lo que solucionó tú problema.

Comment: Discrepo de su comentario, ya que no especifica el entorno de su servidor. Si bien la respuesta pertenece a Windows, su BD podría estar tanto en Windows como en otro SO, por tal motivo dejo en claro que mi respuesta es para los que tienen su BD en Ubuntu. Lo edité para quede más claro.